# Is there a possibility I can give a separate password to access phpmyadmin - XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm doing small system with PHP/MYSQL. From XAMPP security module I gave a password to access the phpmyadmin. The same password I am using in the config file of my PHP. Yesterday my boss came up with a paculiar request ( it's an order basically) :). The request is he should be able to set the password and change the password of phpmyadmin when ever he wants. Now I can give him access to XAMPP security, but if he change the password I need to change password in the config file of my php also. Or else I will get error in my PHP program. I'm just a developer, don't know much about server configurations.

Comment: Twelve factor app: Store config in the environment

Comment: ohhh. So it means the php config file has to take from XAMPP environment?